# bug-tracker and wiki for project specifications

Tags: project-management, bug-tracking, mediawiki, specifications

### SHORT QUESTION

If you want to skip the details below, here's the short question:

I want to know if you keep your app's specifications similarly, in a bugtracker + a wiki and how do you split the information for good management. I look for a simple solution or just a point to start.

### DETAILS

I need to keep track of the features for a web app that I want to build. So, I've used MediaWiki to gather a list of features.

For each feature, I have a wiki page where I include functional specs, technical specs and various related brainstormings in FreeMind format or plain text. Also, I include a series of open-questions related to it as TODOs and lots of images for various use cases. I found the wiki to be an excellent place where to keep all these.

I have a page in the wiki with all features transcluded manually so I can see them all in one page, in a specific format.
I also have a page in the wiki where I state what's the goal for v1.0, and a manually transcluded list of features for this version.

In the bug tracker(I use ClockingIT), I want to keep track of the tasks, bugs, etc. in order to build version 1.0 of the product.

### ISSUE

Since I keep all features(well, the major features at least) in the wiki, I now feel the need to duplicate them in the bug tracker. Also, after brainstorming on V1.0, I realized there are many smaller features(that are too small to include in the wiki) that I'll need to keep track of in the bug tracker.

The problem is that I end up with 2 systems that will keep and manage the set of features and lots of duplicates will appear, like:

- which features get in V1.0 -> this exists in the wiki as a page and the bugtracker keeps a milestone for this; moving a feature from v1.0 to another version, will mean to update both the bugtracker and the wiki
- in the bugtracker I add comments as logs for what I do while working on the feature, so the wiki will get deprecated because some part of the brainstorming moves into the bugtracker
- the wiki will tend to contain the major features while the bugtracker will contain minor features(like add a button to show/hide a section or something)...but the limit between major and minor features is very subjective and will tend to get messy so I'll have a hard time searching for a feature - I'll have to search in both wiki and bugtracker or I'll have to remember if it was a major or a minor feature

### QUESTION

Since I need to keep the features in the wiki because it is an excellent tool for brainstorming, information keeping, etc. what should I include in the bugtracker? How can I efficiently separate these two tools' functionality so they integrate well with each-other and I don't get to duplicate any(or small amount of) data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something mixed. On the wiki, there is a requirements page (among other pages), which describes the features and delivery data. Some features has separated topics where design/implementation details are explained. The requirements topic includes links to bugs with a short description of the bug/feature. Not all features are reflected as bugs. All bugs are listed in the current release section, if they are planned to be fixed in that release. A separated link goes to bug-tracking system to show all the bugs for the product (there are many products in the bug tracker). So:

- all features, bug fixes are listed on the requirements page under a particular release;
- bug tracking system contains bugs found during testing;
- there is no exact definition which requests go to the bug tracker and which don't. An external reviewer may report feature requests as tickets in the bug tracker.
- the key point is to keep all the requirements together and organized per release.

Maybe there are better ways to organize things, but this one is the simplest to me, and doesn't require lots of time.

Comment: I'm glad to know you use something similar - it's great we can share experiences. I'll add my feedback as separate comments.

Comment: @1: "On the wiki, there is a requirements page" - so for version 1.0 you keep a page with all features listed? Wouldn't that duplicate the items in the bug tracker for which you also have to set a target version?

Comment: @tanderson I don't keep initial requirements/features in the bug tracker.

Comment: @2: "Some features has separated topics where design/implementation details are explained" - for such a feature do you have a page which links to 2 separate pages(design and implementation)?

Comment: @tanderson depends on the volume of the information. Two sections (Design Notes, Impl Notes) in a topic, or two separated topics.

Comment: @3: if you have a requirement to "rename items in a table" which goes into initial specifications(in the wiki), and when implementing you find that you also need to "be able to order items in that table by drag&drop", does this go into the bug tracker? so, what happens with   missed features from initial planning?

Comment: @tanderson last time happened something similar ("support reordering of files in the table of input files" request came from marketing people) I opened a bug, but this doesn't become a ceremony, I could just add it to the requirements list. I remove features from the initial features list as they are implemented. Sequential releases contain separated information about the features coming from the initial requirements, current requirements, bugs.

Comment: is there any guideline you followed for how you organize things between wiki and bug-tracker? maybe a blog or something? it would help me very much to have some best practices and I feel they must exist somewhere I didn't find yet

Comment: "I remove features from the initial features list as they are implemented" - do you remove the features from the wiki completely?

Comment: "Sequential releases contain separated information about the features coming from the initial requirements" - do you make a reference to the same feature from the initial features list or you have per-version specific things you write about each feature?

Comment: @tanderson 1. No. the reqs topic contains all the bug for the release and a link to the product page in bug tracker. 2. No. The feature migrates from "Initial Reqs" to the section for appropriate release. 3. If the feature implemented completely, it is listed in the release, otherwise it remains in the reqs list, and the release section contains a short note how the feature partially implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to customize for your needs but have you seen trac : http://trac.edgewall.org/.

This will serve many of your purpose. It combines bug tracker with wiki and other aspects.

Trac is an enhanced wiki and issue tracking system for software development projects. It provides an interface to  Subversion (or other version control systems), an integrated Wiki and convenient reporting facilities.

Comment: I've tested Trac but it really lacks time tracking,no hierarchical display of tickets(I need to have dependencies),  and I've used MediaWiki for a long time so I don't see the benefits of Trac's wiki. ClockingIT looks really simple to use, has lots of drag-drop functionalities - e.g. to move a task to another project, milestone, status, etc., time tracking is great with the Timer Window gadget that displays all in progress tasks, and reporting capabilities are also great; it also has a wiki but I prefer MediaWiki since I want to include FreeMind files,use it's templating system,etc.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but if you like Trac and have strong reasons for using it, I'd be glad to know